# How do i get my support vector regression to work to plot my polynomial graph

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have compiled my code for a polynomial graph, but it is not plotting. I am using SVR(support vector regression) from scikit learn and my code is below. It is not showing any error message, and it is just showing my data. I don't know what is going on. Does anyone? It is not even showing anything on the variable console describing my data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



df = pd.read_csv('coffee.csv')
print(df)

df = df[['Date','Amount_prod','Beverage_index']]

x = np.array(df.Amount_prod)
y = np.array(df.Beverage_index)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(
x, y, test_size=0.2)

x_train = np.pad(x, [(0,0)], mode='constant')
x_train.reshape((26,1))

y_train = np.pad(y, [(0,0)], mode='constant')
y_train.reshape((26,1))

x_train = np.arange(26).reshape((26, 1))
x_train = x.reshape((26, 1))
c = x.T
np.all(x_train == c)

x_test = np.arange(6).reshape((-1,1))
x_test = x.reshape((-1,1))
c2 = x.T
np.all(x_test == c2)

y_test = np.arange(6).reshape((-1,1))
y_test = y.reshape((-1,1))
c2 = y.T
np.all(y_test ==c2)

svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=2)
y_poly = svr_poly.fit(x_train,y_train).predict(x_train)




plt.scatter(x_train, y_train, color='black')
plt.plot(x_train,  y_poly)

plt.show()
```

Data sample:

```
 Date   Amount_prod Beverage_index
    1990    83000         78
    1991    102000        78
    1992    94567         86
    1993    101340        88
    1994    96909         123
    1995    92987         101
    1996    103489        99
    1997    99650         109
    1998    107849        110
    1999    123467        90
    2000    112586        67
    2001    113485        67
    2002    108765        90
```

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with the code as such. Although a caveat: Give some dummy values to both x and y of length 26 each and see if the plot shows up. If it does, then you know that your code is functioning properly, else you need to figure out if your data is in the correct format. Try to eliminate various possibilities and you surely would be able to arrive at the solution.

Comment: Could you give some data to make this example fully reproducible. It's a bit hard to follow otherwise. On first inspection I feel you might be better served spliting the y_poly assignment line into two. Namely.    svr = svr_poly.fit(x_t,y_t) and y_poly = svr.predict(x_t)

Comment: @draco_alpine i have added some sample data to my question. Thank you!

Comment: I am actually just practicing with this, and more interested in getting the graph through.  not really worried about the prediction since there is clearly no causation here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below. Support Vector Machines expect their input to have zero mean and unit variance. It's not the plot, that's blocking. It's the call to `fit`.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

svr_poly = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=2))
y_poly = svr_poly.fit(x_train,y_train).predict(x_train)
```

Comment: Doing that is showing this error **DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype int64 was converted to float64 by StandardScaler.
  warnings.warn(msg, DataConversionWarning)**

Comment: it is plotting btw but just throwing this error messag, and i am wondering why.

Comment: Beverage_Index is probably stored as an int64. To mean normalize you need to be able to divide in float64 type. You can basically ignore the warning.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on Matt's answer a little. Nothing about your plotting is in error. When you call to svr_poly.fit with 'unreasonably' large numbers no error is thrown (but I still had to kill my kernel). By tinkering the exponent value in this code I reckoned that you could get up to 1e5 before it breaks, but not more. Hence your problem. As Matt says, applying the StandardScaler will solve your problems.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



x_train = np.random.rand(10,1)      # between 0 and 1
y_train = np.random.rand(10,)       # between 0 and 1
x_train = np.multiply(x_train,1e5)  #scaling up to 1e5
svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=1)
svr_poly.fit(x_train,y_train)#.predict(x_train)
y_poly = svr_poly.predict(x_train)

plt.scatter(x_train, y_train, color='black')
plt.plot(x_train,  y_poly)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yea i should have preprocessed and normalized my data. Thanks for the help!